# Does static initialization order fiasco apply to block-scope static variables?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

The question pretty much like in the topic, I couldn’t find clear answer to this as almost every example covers two namespace scope instances depending on each other. An example:

a.hpp

```
class MyGlobal {/*definition*/};
extern const MyGlobal global;
```

a.cpp

```
const MyGlobal global;
```

b.hpp

```
void myFunc();
```

b.cpp

```
extern const MyGlobal global;
class MyLocalStatic
{
    public:
    MyLocalStatic() { /* do something with global */ }
    
};

void myFunc()
{
    static MyLocalStatic s;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() { myFunc(); }
```

Let’s say that both `MyGlobal` and `MyStaticLocal` have some non-trivial constructors and so are initialized during dynamic initialization.
I know that compiler can defer dynamic initialization until the variable actually used. But what if it’s not used in the same TU at all? When will compiler decide to initialize it?

Another question: if `global` is constant initialized I assume there’s no problem. But is it possible that `s` is also constant initialized (and still depends on `global` somehow) or this is not possible?

Would be grateful for some quotes from the standard :)

Comment: A static variable in function scope is initialized the first time the function is called. Not relevant here, but the initialization is thread-safe. You have some more [specifics here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables).

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks I wasn't aware of this tag, added :D

Comment: @super My question is not when `MyLocalStatic` is intialized, but rather "what guarantees that `MyGlobal` is initialized before it" (if anything)

Comment: Well, the fact that it is initialized the first time the function is called should tell you that the global variable is guaranteed to be initialized before it. So even if you didn't ask when `MyLocalStatic` was initialized, my comment still answers your question.

Comment: @super the standard says that _It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main._ . So which part of standard makes the guarantee you are talking about?

Comment: In your `do something with global` part, the variable is `odr-use`ed. So it's initialization is guaranteed to happen before.

Comment: @super indeed that very same paragraph I quoted mentions odr-use, but **ONLY** with respect to functions or variables defined in the same translation unit, which is not the case here. Besides, if this rule would apply to `extern` variables, then it would never be possible to use something before its odr-use so it would remove the SIOF problem completely I think?

Comment: It says that the initialization will happen before the first odr-use of ANYTHING in the same translation unit. The variable itself is also part of the translation unit, so using said variable is guaranteed to make the deferred initialization happen before that point. This is however specific to deferred initialization, and doesn't really effect SIOF at all. SIOF is generally only a problem when the static initialization of one thing depends on the static initialization of another thing, and if they reside in different TUs we don't know the order of initialization.

Comment: @super let's say in file `1.cpp` we have globals `A a` and `DependsOnA b`. In file `2.cpp` I have `extern DependsOnA b` and `DependsOnB c`. If `2.cpp` gets compiled before `1.cpp` then if odr-used rule applies to `extern`s it would mean that `DependsOnA a` gets initialized before `A a`, which breaks the guarantee that globals are initialized in order in same TU. That's why I'm very confused about this :|

Comment: First of all, the order of compilation is not relevant. It's the order of initialization. In that example the odr-rule doesn't come into play because it's not a question of deferred initialization. It's a question of initialization order. `c` depends on a variable with static storage duration from another TU, so SIOF may occur. Seems you are confusing the odr-used guarantee from deferred initialzation, and that it would somehow have an impact of SIOF, which it does not.

Comment: From my understanding, the odr-used guarantee with deferred initialization basically says: "The compiler is allowed to initialize this thing with static storage duration after main has been entered, and it may even omit to initialize it at all if it wants. BUT we give you the guarantee that if you touch this variable or anything in it's TU in any way the initialization is guaranteed to happen before that point." Or even more simply put, if the initialization of something is deferred, it's initialization is still guaranteed to always happen before it's odr-used.

Answer (score 2):

Function-local `static` variables are created when control reaches their declaration for the first time. In your case it'll happen after entering `main`, at which point `global` is surely initialized.

> is it possible that `s` is also constant initialized

Yes.

> ...and still depends on `global` somehow

Yes, only if `global` is `constexpr`.

If a variable is constant-initialized, there's nothing to worry about. There's no static-init-order fiasco at compile-time.

Comment: Only as a side-note: Independent from the static initialization order fiasco, there's still a small chance to mess up things: Multiple different definitions for the constant variable across multiple translation units for the external linkage case (UB).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat well you see the standard does not seem to agree that "`global` is surely initialized" (or I'm reading it wrong?): _It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of `main`. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of `main`, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized._

Comment: Does odr-use in this context apply to `extern` variables too?  But then there should be no issue with SIOF at all?